# How much heat is generated by a Li-ion phosphate battery during discharge

Tags: lithium-ion, heat, discharge

I am designing an enclosed container with 10 kWh 50 V battery in it which requires me to actively remove the heat. The battery feeds an 8.8 kVA inverter.
Assume I have a load of 8 kW, which would draw 160 amp at 50 V.

One of the sources https://batteryuniversity.com/learn/archive/how_does_internal_resistance_affect_performance referred to small Li-ion and gave internal resistance of about 320 mΩ to 340 mΩ.
Other sources were more academic and incomprehensible. Most addressed charging - nothing on large batteries.

If this is the case the internal heat generated would be I<sup>2</sup> × R = 160<sup>2</sup> × 320/1000 = 8192 W, an impossible result.

Either the internal resistance is wrong or I am using the wrong logic. How much heat would the battery create during discharge?

Comment: A battery would normally be rated in Ah or Wh but never VAh as it is not AC so there is no reactive component (which is where VA is used). Can you [edit] your question to fix this and quote the discharge in current (A) or power (W).

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying here. Your units don't work out at *all*.

Comment: Can you quote a source for battery resistance. I'd that for a cell or your actual battery and what cells are used in what configuration,?

Comment: Maximum power transfer theorem shows that max power is Vbat/2 into 330 milliohm or about 1800 Watt. Your resistance figure MUST be wrong.

Comment: There must be a datasheet for the batteries you are considering!

Comment: @Russel   I know I am wrong. That is why I posted to look for the answer! My question is both academic and practical. I have looked at a couple of detailed spec sheets. They refer to maximum temperatures and reduction in power, but not heat generated. I have just found my first reference against a 6 kWh battery.stating:  Internal impedance measured at 1 kHz <30 mOhm. Using 30 mOhm at 160 Amp would give internal heat generated as 768 watt. I think I can consider this as correct. Thank you all for commenting.

Answer (score 1):

Either your battery is 10 kWh or 10 kAh but not normally referred to as 10 kVAh (a term we might use in AC circuits due to power-factor).

If your battery's internal resistance is 320 mΩ then the maximum current you could draw into a dead short (not recommended) would be \$ I = \frac V R = \frac {50}{0.33} = 150 \ \text A \$ but you would have zero volts at the terminals so no power.

I suggest that your internal resistance calculation is wrong or your battery can only supply about 15 A with a 10% voltage drop.

Comment: Thanks. Rephrased question. You are correct in that batteries are rated in kWh. With DC, PF = 1 then kVah is also correct but unconventional..

Comment: Edit again to show how you figured 320 mΩ. That's got to be wrong.